# Opencart normal urls don't work anymore

Tags: .htaccess, routes, opencart

I'm facing a problem with Opencart where only the SEO urls are working and all the 'normal' urls like 
**index.php?route=common/home**
etc have stopped working. They lead to a page not found error.

This is my site : [www.24x7style.com](http://www.24x7style.com)

I haven't made any changes to my site recently..What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Not all your non-SEO URLs are leading to errors. For example, http://24x7style.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart seems to be working. The search URLs are also working: http://24x7style.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=nyassa

None of your account/* URLs are working. Perhaps you could check your catalog/controllers/account/* files, make sure they are intact.